# QHeaderView::sectionCountChanged how to know which section was added

Tags: c++, qt, qheaderview

I wanted to know if there was a way to determine which section was inserted that changed the section count. What I am trying to accomplish is to move the order of newly inserted section to the end. So that newly inserted columns are displayed at the end. Any suggestions on how I could accomplish this ?

Comment: What class are you using to add columns?

Comment: All the columns are already in the model. The QfilterProxy simply hides or shows new columns

Comment: can you post the code your having trouble with?